# Running Nightwatch.js tests via Jenkins - Windows size issue

Tags: selenium, jenkins, nightwatch.js

If I run a test manually via CMD, the window size is set as defined in the test (e.g. .resizeWindow(1680,1050)). 
[window size via CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URnPI.png)

If execute the same test on the workstation via Jenkins, the window size is smaller than defined in the test (e.g. 1034x663) what causes test failures in some situations.
[window size via Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJKkc.png)

What could be the reason for such behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

try changing the browser to phantomJS

Comment: The screen size parameter is applied but Nightwatch tests have several other issues (e.g. locating elements) with this browser which does not happen in other browsers

Answer (score 0):

If an element is not visible on screen, nightwatch does not manage to click on it.

In your failing tests, you need to replace calls to

```
browser.click(hiddenElementSelector);
```

By

```
// Will scroll to the element
browser.moveToElement(hiddenElementSelector);
// Then nightwatch will successfully click on it
browser.click(hiddenElementSelector);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `xvfb` as virtual monitor you can try with this and expand the virtual window:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1900x1200x16" npm run your_nightwatch_tests
```

Comment: Yes, I came across this solution but my testing agent is not running on Linux OS.

Comment: I suggest you try with the --verbose option in both cases, and look at the first request / response that Nightwatch outputs.  It will begin "INFO Request: POST /wd/hub/session".  Are the browser details identical?